In which cases outputs of basename "$x" and echo "${x##*/}" differ?
In the following case outputs of basename "$x" and echo "${x##*/}" are not differ:
$ x=xxx/yyy ; basename "$x" ; echo "${x##*/}"
yyy
yyy

In which cases (if any) outputs of basename "$x" and echo "${x##*/}" differ?

The specification of basename includes the following:

SYNOPSIS
basename string [suffix]

DESCRIPTION
The string operand shall be treated as a pathname […]. The string string shall be converted to the filename corresponding to the last pathname component in string and then the suffix string suffix, if present, shall be removed. This shall be done by performing actions equivalent to the following steps in order:

If string is a null string, it is unspecified whether the resulting string is . or a null string. In either case, skip steps 2 through 6.

If string is //, it is implementation-defined whether steps 3 to 6 are skipped or processed.

If string consists entirely of <slash> characters, string shall be set to a single <slash> character. In this case, skip steps 4 to 6.

If there are any trailing <slash> characters in string, they shall be removed.

If there are any <slash> characters remaining in string, the prefix of string up to and including the last <slash> character in string shall be removed.

If the suffix operand is present, is not identical to the characters remaining in string, and is identical to a suffix of the characters remaining in string, the suffix suffix shall be removed from string. Otherwise, string is not modified by this step. It shall not be considered an error if suffix is not found in string.


The resulting string shall be written to standard output.

Your ${x##*/} gets expanded according to this specification:

${parameter##[word]}

Remove Largest Prefix Pattern. The word shall be expanded to produce a pattern. The parameter expansion shall then result in parameter, with the largest portion of the prefix matched by the pattern deleted.

So it basically does what the step number 5 in the specification of basename should do. You are asking about basename "$x" (as opposed to basename "$x" suffix), so the step number 6 is irrelevant. This means that (almost*) all differences between basename "$x" and echo "${x##*/}" must come from the steps 1 to 4. Examples:
# from step 1 (there may or may not be a difference,
# depending on implementation of basename)
x=''; basename "$x"; echo "${x##*/}"

# from step 2 (there may or may not be a difference,
# depending on implementation of basename)
x='//foo'; basename "$x"; echo "${x##*/}"

# from step 3
x='/////'; basename "$x"; echo "${x##*/}"

# from step 4
x='foo/'; basename "$x"; echo "${x##*/}"


* I wrote "almost" because there are few additional possibilities. Among them:

basename may interpret arguments as options and also echo possibly supports some options (by POSIX it shall not; but GNU echo does, echo builtins in several shells do). This leads to differences of their own type:
# there may or may not be differences and/or errors
x=--help; basename "$x"; echo "${x##*/}"
x=-n;     basename "$x"; echo "${x##*/}"
x=--;     basename "$x"; echo "${x##*/}"

See What does -- (double dash / double hyphen) mean? and Why is printf better than echo?

echo is usually a shell builtin, but basename is usually an external program; so if you break your $PATH…
(PATH=; x='xxx/yyy'; basename "$x"; echo "${x##*/}")



